# Is there a shell script to send notifications on mail events?

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

I've never written an apple script before so I am wondering if there's a way to write a script that continuously (maybe at intervals of 10 minutes) checks my inbox and sends a notification on my mac if there's a new email in inbox (microsoft exchange). (That being said, I also don't mind a python script, anything that gives this functionality is welcome)

Is there a shell of this so I could start on what's hopefully an easy scripting problem?

Comment: Mac Mail already has this feature with [notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvzhe.png) when emails are received either [by push or on a fetch schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjOWa.png). We're not a code writing service, if you're not using the Mail app you'll need to expand your question with specifically what you need assistance with, such as what service and what part of your existing code you've tried doesn't work.

Comment: Abby and @josh - now it's clear the wisdom of grg on being specific and showing some code or details so an answer can be given. there's a great answer here, but perhaps it's not to your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Web mail isn't going to be a basic scripting topic, so since you're new you'll need to have a mail client set up.

Assuming that's the case, heres a script that checks for new mail by comparing dates of latest messages. It checks every 10min and will send a notification if there's new mail.

1. Open Script Editor
2. Copy and Paste the script
3. Go to File>Export
4. File Format = `Application`
5. Make sure `Stay open after after script handler` is checked
6. Open the application

---

```
tell application "Mail"
set new1 to date received of (first message of inbox)
repeat
    check for new mail
    delay 5 --wait until all new messages are in the box 
    set new2 to date received of (first message of inbox)
    if new2 is not equal to new1 then
        display notification "You've got Mail." with title "New Mail"
    end if

    ## For the AOL Effect ##

    # do shell script "say \"You've got mail\""
    set new1 to new2
    delay 600 -- 10 min in seconds 
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Putting aside how this answer presumes OP is talking about Mail, this solution only works if the message is received within the 5 second period of your delay, not if it's during the rest of the 10 minutes.

Comment: I think this answer has numerous issues with it.  The OP stated he's inexperienced with AppleScript, and having this script constantly open and running in, say, _Script Editor_ is not going to be a plausible solution.  However, there's no indication this is a _"stay-open"_ application script (no `on idle` handler), which would be a slightly better implementation; an ever better method would be to create a `launchd` plist, but this hasn't been suggested. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ Also, I'm not convinced that `first message of inbox` is a reliable means of determining if there's new mail; the order of the messages might not always be by date, so `new2 is not equal to new1` might be satisfied simply by re-ordering the messages by sender.  And, of course, as @grg pointed out, the use of `delay` here is poorly thought out.

Comment: @grg Yes. I made it this way intentionally. The OP stated “at intervals of 10 minutes”. I will edit my answer to address the during rest of 10 min.

Comment: I think people have highlighted the problem already.. I wouldn't need something like this if I was using Mail. I need to grab the information from the web

Comment: @grg I have edited it. Apparently, I copied the old version of my script when posting my answer. The new one has already address the 10min issue.

Comment: @Abby Please edit your question with what website you're actually using!

Comment: @grg If Abby replies that she cannot set it up with mail. Then I will delete this answer.

Comment: @CJK I addressed this will the edited answer. I copied over the old version of the script by accident. The new one addresses part of the problems you had with it. And I added the export instructions at the top, I stupidly assumed that this would be assumed by the OP.

Comment: @CJK I just tested this. Even if mail is sorted a different way it **will still work.**

Comment: I have edited the question. I'm mainly using exchange account !

Comment: @Abby Ok. Can you set up using mail?

Comment: no not really. I actually stopped using Mail because of an issue I encountered.

Comment: @Abby This is what we call and [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Let us assist you will your original problem, "the issue [you] encountered".  Can you create a new question so we can assist you with that?

Comment: Just a note to say that if you’re recommending this as a _stay open_ application, an `on idle` handler is a better implementation than a continuous `repeat` loop with a `delay`.  There should also be a means of terminating the application within the script (although, obviously, one can terminate the application via the dock, but it’s bad practice not to have a built-in method).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apple's Mail.app, you can use the built-in macOS Notification system to do this without a script. Go to System Preferences > Notifications and scroll down the list of apps on the left and select Mail. Select the **Alerts** Mail alert style for the simplest notification. The **Badge app icon** option just puts an badge on the Mail app icon in the Dock and the badge increments the total number of new emails as they arrive. This is less intrusive than **Alerts**, which persist on-screen until dismissed.

[image]